# Submit the value without the mask in PrimeFaces <p:inputMask> component

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there a way to submit to the model just the raw value without the mask (format) in the PrimeFaces `<p:inputMask>` component?

I mean, if I have this mask `999.999.999-99` in the `mask` attribute and the component displays `123.456.789-10` as the value entered by the user, I would like to get in the backing bean property just `12345678910` as the value, not `123.456.789-10`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write a converter to convert between the value in you backend and the value you want to use in your UI. For example:

```java
@FacesConverter("myConverter")
public class MyConverter implements Converter {

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, String string) {
        if (string == null || string.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        return string.replace(".", "").replace("-", "");
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic, Object o) {
        final String value = (String) o;
        if (value == null || value.length() != 11) {
            return null;
        }
        return value.substring(0, 3) + "."
                + value.substring(3, 6) + "."
                + value.substring(6, 9) + "-"
                + value.substring(9);
    }

}
```

Which can be used as:

```html
<p:inputMask value="#{testView.string}"
             converter="myConverter"
             mask="999.999.999-99"/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer, Jasper. That's exactly (the converter) what I was doing before, but I was looking for something simpler. It seems that for now there's no other way of achieving this. Just for the record, my `getAsString` method is just `return value;` and my `getAsObject` method is `if (value == null) return null; return Pattern.compile("[^\\d]").matcher(value).replaceAll("");`. `<p:inputMask>` should have a simple boolean attribute for us to configure this, without the need to write a converter.

Comment: There is also the client side widget method `getValueUnmasked()` if you need it in the UI. or in JS code and can submit it in a hidden input that way.